# how to crawl a site only given domain url with scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, scrape

I am trying to use scrapy for crawling a website, but there's no sitemap or page indices for the website. How can I crawl all pages of the website with scrapy?

I just need to download all the pages of the site without extracting any item. Do I only need to set following all links in the Rule of Spider? But I don't know whether or not scrapy will avoid replicate urls in this way.

Comment: Why not just loop through all links on the website and crawl away?

Comment: @enginefree Looping throught all links is the feasible way, but I don't know how to set it with scrapy.

Comment: If you don't want to scrap items then why u want to use scrapy. just use any website downloader and it will do everything for you

Comment: @user1937 I have other python code to parse the html response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer myself. With the `CrawlSpider` class, we just need to set variable `allow=()` in the `SgmlLinkExtractor` function. [As the documentation says](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#topics-link-extractors):

> allow (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match all links.

Answer (score 5):

In your `Spider`, define `allowed_domains` as a list of domains you want to crawl.

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
```

Then you can use `response.follow()` to follow the links.  See [the docs for Spiders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) and [the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Alternatively, you can filter the domains with a `LinkExtractor` (like [David Thompson mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14297053/5031373)).

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }
        for a in LinkExtractor(allow_domains=['quotes.toscrape.com']).extract_links(response):
            yield response.follow(a, callback=self.parse)
```